# PHP Syntax Question

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm drawing a blank for some reason on how to access this information in an object (It's a Zend_Db_Table_Row, but I think that's beside the point).  Here's the print_r, I'd like to get just the array assigned to [_data:protected]

```
MyClassName Object
(
[_data:protected] => Array
    (
        [param1] => 1
        [param2] => Some info
        [param3] => ....
    )

... lots more unneeded info such as 'cleandata' and table schema information
```

I know I can access all the data using $instance->param1, etc, but I'm assigning it to a session and would like to just be able to say

`$sessionNamespace = $instance->data;`

...as to not store the table schema info and not have to iterate through the array and assign it manually.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about `Zend_Db_Table_Row::toArray()`?

Answer (score 1):

Because it has `:protected`, means it has been declared `protected` and therefore you can't access it. The actual class, or a class derived from it (that `extends` it) has to pass it to you with a function call.

You might want to check the API for a `getData()` type method that returns all the data, or `serialize()` if the object supports serialization.

**Edit:** And there one is: As Zerkms suggested, you can use `toArray()` to access it.